# SD card doesn't work properly

Tags: arduino-uno, sd

I have this [SD-card module](https://www.miniinthebox.com/it/p/sd-card-module_p407346.html?currency=EUR&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&country_code=it&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&adword_mt=&adword_ct=202539328488&adword_kw=&adword_pos=1o3&adword_pl=&adword_net=g&adword_tar=&adw_src_id=50918876091_866086207_44403958060_pla-331029837337&gclid=Cj0KCQjw4_zVBRDVARIsAFNI9eB_Yz3q4c_ig1ezRy2QsX2l2pTvPGu9WDVuPkofQqx7XJpWJ0KTC54aAnSGEALw_wcB). I have formatted the SD with [this tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). My problem is that the **Arduino Uno** can't initialize the SD. I tried with this script:

```
// include the SD library:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// set up variables using the SD utility library functions:
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;

const int chipSelect = 7;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Doesn't work properly");
  } else{
    Serial.println("works properly");
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

And the result:

```
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
works properly
works properly
works properly
works properly
works properly
works properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
Doesn't work properly
works properly
works properly
works properly
Doesn't work properly
```

The "works properly" happens, usually, when I move the module slightly. Is there a way to repair the module?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have unreliable wiring connections.  Your module won't directly plug into an Arduino Uno, so how have you physically made the electrical connections?

Comment: I use: MISO -> Pin 12,
MOSI -> Pin 11,
SCK -> Pin 13,
SDCS ->Pin 10,
5V -> 5V,
GND -> GND

Comment: Yes, but how are these connections **physically** made?

Comment: With Jumper Wires like this: https://www.exploringarduino.com/parts/jumper-wires/

Comment: Show us a photopgraph of your actual setup.

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img923/318/ptdhHE.jpg

Comment: Manufacturing flaws in such jumper wires are not unknown, and the connections there or in the Arduino can wear.  Also long wire runs are not encouraged for things like this, either signals or power/ground.

Comment: Your stated wiring doesn't appear to match your code or picture.  To which signal is the green wire connected?

Comment: I connect the SDCS (green) to Pin 7 as in the code above; in the previous comment I make a typo. Could be a problem with the module?

Comment: `I have formatted the SD with this tool.` .... this does not describe what you actually did

Comment: I formatted the sd with the tool that is linked.